# Doxygen - group functions and have them search-able in the index

Tags: c++, doxygen

I used doxygen grouping like this:

> DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC = 1

```
//@{
//! Same documentation for both members. Details ...
void func1InGroup1();
void func2InGroup1();
//@}
```

and this generates the same documentation for the two functions.. the only problem is: the functions are not showing in the html index on the beginning and I can't click on the items to go to the common description.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with grouping. Solved now.